# Trying to change settings -> firefox downloads options.php instead

Tags: options

I just ran into some trouble with my wordpress installation. I tried to change a setting in the backend, but when I hit save, instead of saving my settings, the download dialogue opened; it said I was downloading the options.php file. I downloaded it and opened it, it contained the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>200 OK</title>
</head><body>
<h1>OK</h1>
<p>The server is temporarily unable to service your
request due to maintenance downtime or capacity
problems. Please try again later.</p>
</body></html>
```

This happened with two independent wordpress installations on the same virtual server (they use different MySQL databases). Is this just a temporary error due to some maintenance or something at Strato (where my Webspace is hosted)? If not, how can I fix this?

Comment: Is your host using Nginx? It sounds like you need to open a help ticket with the host.

Comment: Please don't use swear words. If you need to swear, do it by yourself or in your head, but not in your posts. Thank you

Comment: (at) Pieter Ok °v° @RyanLoremIpsum No, my site is hosted by Strato ...